# Why i'm getting the option to use nodeValue insted of just Value?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, nodevalue

i'm writing an html page that gets a name, an address and a phone number to practice validation. when the javascript function tries to get the length of the value in the inputs i get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

i dont know what nodeValue means but i simply want to get the value in the input.

this is the part of the code in the javascript that gives me the error:

```
function Validate(nameInput, lastNameInput, addressInput, phoneInput)
{

var errorSpan = document.getElementById("errorSpan");
var okSpan = document.getElementById("okSpan");

var nameErrSpan = document.getElementById("nameErrSpan");
var lastNameErrSpan = document.getElementById("lastNameErrSpan");
var addressErrSpan = document.getElementById("addressErrSpan");
var phoneErrSpan = document.getElementById("phoneErrSpan");

var nameLength = nameInput.nodeValue.length;
var lNameLength = lastNameInput.nodeValue.length;
var addressLength = addressIput.nodeValue.length;
var phoneLength = phoneInput.nodeValue.length;
```

what do i need to change to just get the value in the inputs and measure them?

here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Validation Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <span>First name:</span><br />
    <input type="text" id="firstName" /> <span id="nameErrSpan" class="nHidden">Name Must Be Between 3 - 10 Letters</span>
    <br>


    <span>Last name:</span><br />
    <input type="text" id="lastName" /> <span id="lastNameErrSpan" class="lnHidden">Last Name Must Be Between 3 - 10 Letters</span>
    <br>

    <span>Address:</span><br />
    <input type="text" id="address" /> <span id="addressErrSpan" class="adHidden">Address Must Be Between 10 - 25 Letters</span>
    <br>

    <span>Phone number:</span><br />
    <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" /> <span id="phoneErrSpan" class="pHidden">Phone Must Be Between 3 - 10 Digits</span>
    <br>

    <button onclick="Validate(firstName, lastName, address, phoneNumber)">Check</button><br />

    <span id="errorSpan" class="hidden">Missing fields</span><br />
    <span id="okSpan" class="hidden">All fields are filled</span><br />

    <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button><br />


</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="registrationForm.css">
<script src="registrationForm.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have `<input>` elements inside your `<span>`s, you need to get the input elements, and then use `.value` to get the text that was entered into it.

Comment: @Barmar i am getting the input elements.  you can see them in the parantsis right after the function name in the javascript page.  but also i have them in seperate var's with 'getElementById' so i got that coverd

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the automatic globals if I were you, but it's your call. They *are* in the spec now. But there are so many globals, it's easy to use an `id` that doesn't end up creating the automatic global because of a conflict with another global (for instance: `name`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok i accept what you're saying.  i changed all the 'nodeValue' to 'Value' but now i get the same error with just the 'null' turned into 'Undefind'.

Answer (score 2):

To get the text entered into an `input`, you should use `.value`, not `.nodeValue`.

```
var nameLength = nameInput.value.length;
var lNameLength = lastNameInput.value.length;
var addressLength = addressIput.value.length;
var phoneLength = phoneInput.value.length;
```

Comment: I know, but when i write Value the error change from 'null' to 'Undefind'.
Plus i dont get the option of Value with the autoCorrect of visual code.

Comment: `value` not `Value`.

Comment: Thank you! i change the 'nodeValue' to 'value' with the correct spelling and it works. i get the length of the inputs value now!

Answer (score 0):

The value of an `input` element is available from its `value` property. `nodeValue` is a property of **all** DOM nodes, and not relevant to `input` elements.

Comment: Ok i understand the difference now, but if i use Value insted of nodeValue i get the same error with the only difference is the 'null' turns to 'Undefind'.
plus the autocorrect of visual code dont suggest the option of Value, just nodeValue. i dont know why.

Comment: @Dolev: As Barmar said, it's `value`, not `Value`. Case is important. About VS Code: Apparently it doesn't know the element is specifically an `HTMLInputElement`, so it's showing you what's on `HTMLElement` (which has `nodeValue` because it inherits it from `Element`, which inherits it from `Node`).

Comment: thank you, i understand it now, why it's acts like that i why i didnt get the correction i expected!